# Rails - Empty serialized field on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

How should I create a record with a serialized array field to a string.

Like this?

```
ExerciseStudent.create(exercise_id: e.id, student_id: self.id, load: "[]", repetition: "[]")
```

Or simple like this?

```
ExerciseStudent.create(exercise_id: e.id, student_id: self.id, load: "", repetition: "")
```

Later when filled with data I want to look like this:

```
exercise.load == "[15, 20, 30]"
```

My model:

```
class ExerciseStudent < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :load, Array
  serialize :repetition, Array
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :student
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to represent the value as a String instance, just go all in and use Arrays. Since you've told Rails to serialize the attribute it'll handle converting it from an Array to YAML on save and vice versa on load ("load" as in from the database and into the object in memory).

```
exercise.load = [15, 20, 30]
```

And:

```
ExerciseStudent.create(exercise_id: e.id, student_id: self.id, load: [], repetition: [])
```

Comment: Even when I felt Rails couldn't be more awesome. Thanks